# OpenCV: Link given to imread() fails

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV.
I've given a link to the function imread as follows:

`Mat logo = imread("http://files.kurento.org/img/mario-wings.png");`

I've checked and the image exists on the given path. imread() still fails to read it.

Any mistake that I've made?

-Thanks

Comment: I doubt imread is able to fetch http content.

Comment: it [can't](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread), you need to specify a local filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact `imread` is not able to read image data via http.

But it's possible using [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture).

See this little snippet:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture vc;
    vc.open("http://files.kurento.org/img/mario-wings.png");
    if(vc.isOpened() && vc.grab()) {
        cv::Mat logo;
        vc.retrieve(logo);
        cv::namedWindow("t");
        cv::imshow("t", logo);
        cv::waitKey(0);
        vc.release();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I ran it and it showed me the hat of an italian plumber.

Comment: i get "warning: Could not find codec parameters (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:589)" . it works for jpeg files but not for png

Comment: I might be mistaken, but it looks like ffmpeg is unable to decode the image.

Comment: I got the image. Thank you!

Comment: @s1h, I was just wondering, how heavy is this when compared to imread() ?